# Transformations on Tikz/PGF shadings

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shadings

I am trying to produce a figure that depicts the encoding of angular direction as hue to describe domain colouring of complex functions with HSV mapping.

The below example is a MWE that uses the `shadings` library. The only problem with it is that it needs to be flipped vertically so that the green colours encode northern angles and violet encodes southern angles.

[image: HSV color wheel that needs to be flipped]

In the MWE, you will see that I enclosed the `\shade`ed circle in a scope and tried to y-invert the scope. Apparently, the shading is applied to the shape after it is drawn. So removing `yscale=-1` does nothing.

I looked at the source code for the `color wheel` shading and tried to modify it, but x86 assembly is an easier read than the PGF code—I can't make any sense of it. There must be a straightforward way to do this.

Can anyone please reveal to me the silly little argument I don't know about to reverse a gradient or suggest an alternate approach?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\begin{document}
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\WheelRadius}{3}
      %\begin{scope}[yscale=-1] % ← I would have expected this to work.
        \shade[shading=color wheel, shading angle=-90] [even odd rule]
                (0,0) circle (\WheelRadius)
                (0,0) circle (\WheelRadius/2);
      %\end{scope}
      % Labels at cardinal and ordinal directions.
      \foreach \ang/\lab/\dir in {
        0/0/right,
        1/{\pi/4}/{above right},
        2/{\pi/2}/above,
        3/{3\pi/4}/{above left},
        4/{\pi}/left,
        5/{5\pi/4}/{below left},
        7/{7\pi/4}/{below right},
        6/{3\pi/2}/below} {
        \draw (0,0) -- (\ang * 180 / 4:\WheelRadius.1);
        \node [fill=white] at (\ang * 180 / 4:\WheelRadius.2) [\dir] {\scriptsize $\lab$};
      }

      \draw [thick] (0,0) circle (\WheelRadius);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no `fading transform`, I think the only option is to use a `transform canvas` like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\WheelRadius}{3}
\shadedraw[thick, shading=color wheel, shading angle=-90, transform canvas={yscale=-1}, even odd rule]
    (0,0) circle (\WheelRadius)
    (0,0) circle (\WheelRadius/2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Color wheel]

Comment: Wonderful! It works a treat. I assume `transform canvas` performs the transform operation after shading has been drawn over the shape. I'll know soon enough because I'm going to hit the documentation. Also, I like your use of shade-draw to simplify and give me both inner and outer stroke. Thanks so much!

Comment: One more problem. On my beamer slides, I place it in an overlay so that I can position it on the frame with `\tikzset{shift=current page.XY, xshift=…, yshift=…}`. The canvas transform interferes with this, and the disk moves separately and divergently from the polar axes. Any suggestions?

Comment: `transform canvas` can do all sort of things to the canvas(the thing you are drawing on). It should normally be the last way to solve problems, as it can introduce other problems.

Comment: FYI, I bruit forced the overlay problem by putting it in a `\savebox`, and just using the savebox in a node in an overlay. Much better solution anyway, because I re-use it.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/707886/8650

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I propose a solution without using the library `shadings`.  It is based on a loop (constructs colours by angle) and makes no coordinate change.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[evaluate={real \wheelRadius; \wheelRadius = 6;}]
  \foreach \t [evaluate=\t as \h using \t/360] in {0, 1, ..., 359}{%
    \definecolor{tmp}{hsb}{\h, 1, 1}
    \filldraw[tmp, rotate=\t] (0,0)
    -- +(-.5: \wheelRadius) -- +(.5: \wheelRadius ) -- cycle;
  }
  \fill[white] (0,0) circle (\wheelRadius/2);
  
  \draw (0,0) circle (\wheelRadius);
  \foreach \ang/\lab in {%
    0/0, 1/{\pi/4}, 2/{\pi/2}, 3/{3\pi/4}, 4/{\pi},
    5/{5\pi/4}, 6/{3\pi/2}, 7/{7\pi/4}} {
    \draw (0,0) -- (\ang * 180/4: \wheelRadius +.2)
    ([turn]0: 4ex) node[scale=.7] {$\lab$};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Though the original question led to an interesting problem in its own right, I think this solution should be preferred.