# Prevent transform canvas for coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, transformation

Answering this question: [Transformations on Tikz/PGF shadings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/707869/8650) , I could only figure it out using `transform canvas={yscale=-1}`. This flips the colors of the shade. The problem now is that OP has a shifted tikzpicture, so that not only the shade is flipped, but also the coordinates are changed.

The only solution to that problem I could make work it this hack:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shift={(3,-2)}] %should work for any values here
\path (0,0);
\pgfgetlastxy{\macrox}{\macroy}
\shadedraw[thick, shading=color wheel, shading angle=-90, even odd rule, transform canvas={yscale=-1}] 
  (0,-2*\macroy) circle (3) (0,-2*\macroy) circle (3/2);
\fill[red] (0,0) circle[radius=4pt];
\pgfresetboundingbox
\useasboundingbox (-4,-4) rectangle (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Color wheel with red dot in center]

Does anyone have a better way to make the wheel centered at `(0,0)`?

Comment: HI!  I proposed an answer to the question your are talking about without any coordinate change; one can a have a colour wheel centred at a chosen point.